# Mule ESB: Evaluating <choice-when> in mule using Expressions

Tags: mule, esb

I have the following expressiong in mule is this valid:

```
 <choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[message.payload[0]['destination'] == 'SFO']"> 
       <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain"> 
            <request-reply timeout="5000"> 
               <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="Queue1"></jms:outbound-endpoint> 
               <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="Queue2"></jms:inbound-endpoint>  
             </request-reply>  
       </processor-chain>
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2013-11-23 10:11:04,010 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "message.payload[0]['destination'] == 'SFO'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: CaseInsensitiveHashMap
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am getting the input through the when by doing a Select all on a database table in derby.

With Regards
S

Comment: possible duplicate of [MuleESB: Unable to use map-payload to route messages in When](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168882/muleesb-unable-to-use-map-payload-to-route-messages-in-when)

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it seems that your payload is already a map and not an array.

You should use the expression

```
#[message.payload['destination'] == 'SFO']
```

directly.

Comment: <foreach doc:name="Foreach">
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[message.payload['price'] > 750]"                  The payload is a column from a database but I get an error indicating ' Execution of the expression "message.payload['price'] > 750" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)'  any Ideas?

Comment: You need to provide the entire error log,otherwise it is hard to tell