# MuleESB: Unable to use map-payload to route messages in When

Tags: mule, esb

```
<jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint   queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" queryKey="selectAll" pollingFrequency="10000">
            <jdbc-ee:transaction action="NONE"/>
    </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
   <foreach doc:name="Foreach">
<choice doc:name="Choice">
<when expression="#[map-payload:destination] == SFO" >
      <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain"> 

    <logger level="INFO" message="Print 1"/>
            </when> 
<otherwise>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Print 2"/> 
       </otherwise> 
  </choice>

</foreach>
```

when I try to filter based on map-payload, I find that it always hits the othewise clause & not the when clause even though the map-payload contains SFO as destination. What is wrong with my expression?

Here is the Log as you can see it always hit the logger in otherwise never in when.

```
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:33,966 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Print 2
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:33,967 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Print 2
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,955 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Payload is {DESTINATION=LAX, PRICE=5, ID=3}
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,955 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Payload is {DESTINATION=SFO, PRICE=10, ID=2}
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,956 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Destination is MLT
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,957 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Price is 1200
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,957 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Destination is SFO
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,958 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Price is 500
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,959 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Print 2
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,961 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Print 2
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,962 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Print 2
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,963 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Print 2
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,965 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Print 2
INFO  2013-11-23 14:51:43,966 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Print 2
```

Comment: What a bizarre way to format XML :)

Comment: Why is it sometimes `DESTINATION` and sometimes `Destination` and where are the loggers that log these different lines? I can't make sense of the logs when I compare them with the config above.

Comment: And please reformat your XML, it's hard to help you if you don't make a minimum effort to present your information in a clean manner.

Answer (score 0):

`map-payload` is deprecated: if the payload is a map you can get its values directly with MEL.

So assuming you have a `text` column named `destination`, the following should work:

```
<when expression="#[message.payload.destination == 'SFO']" >
```

This works because you iterate on the rows around this expression with `foreach`.

Comment: David,                                                                    This is what I get after adding that change:                                                                   Root Exception stack trace:
[Error: could not access: destination; in class: java.lang.String]
[Near : {... message.payload.destination == ....}]
             ^

Comment: although I can see the destination printed above:                                                                 16:02:42,023 [[ConfluexDemo].ExpreFlow2.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Destination is SFO

Comment: That doesn't make sense: it means that the current payload is a `String` instead of a `Map`, though it should be a `Map` as you're iterating the `List<Map>` coming from `selectAll`.